# Normalization of dlib facial landmark points in python

Tags: python, image-processing, dlib

Is there a python solution to normalize the [dlib landmark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05uIT.jpg) points?
In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537536/normalization-of-facial-landmark-points-in-image-processing) it's explained that dlib with c++ api it's possible but the function is not implemented in the python api yet.

What are the techniques that I can use to normalize these points to make them invariant to orientation of the face, size of eyes, lips etc...?